# How do I correct incorrect parenting

Tags: rigging

The Teeth  don't seem to be parented to DEF-teeth.B.001 and don't move when jaw moves, instead the tongue moves. Do I have to delete the rig to fix this and if so how do I do that.

Comment: If the teeth are a separate object, you can correct it with the parent relationship. If they're part of the object but a separate mesh you can correct it with weight painting.  Unless it's just less work to start over, you should not have to delete the rig, just edit things.  Perhaps you could add a blend file with an example of the problem to your question?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Object Properties > Relations* panel to change your object's parent/child status.

[image]